# Пояснительные члены

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Нева обстроена с таким расчетом: (каким?) создать величественные ансамбли. Здесь поясняется слово "такой". Получается, "создать" здесь определение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Нева обстроена с таким расчетом — **создать величественные ансамбли.***

С помощью тире обособлено несогласованное определение, выраженное инфинитивом. Такие определения носят **пояснительный характер**.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

3. Несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова *а именно*, отделяется посредством тире: Но прекрасен **данный** жребий — просиять и умереть (Бр.); Мы все одержимы **одной** страстью — сопротивляться (Кетл.);  Откуда вы право взяли себе **такое** — судить? Подобные определения носят пояснительный характер [см. § 23, п. 1].